# Greenbot Eventbus 3.0: What is the difference between onEvent, onEventMainThread, onEventBackgroundThread and onEventAsync?

Tags: java, android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

I am a bit confused with the usage of `onEvent`, `onEventMainThread`, `onEventBackgroundThread` and `onEventAsync` in [Greenrobot's EventBus 3.0](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

From what I see in the [documentation](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/delivery-threads-threadmode/):

- `onEvent` is used with `ThreadMode.POSTING` (default)
- `onEventMainThread` is used with `ThreadMode.MAIN`
- `onEventBackgroundThread` is used with `ThreadMode.BackgroundThread`
- `onEventAsync` is used with `ThreadMode.ASYNC`

But in the case where the event is posted from a background thread:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEventMainThread(MyEvent event) {
    // some UI manipulation
}
```

Has exactly the same behavior as:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
    // some UI manipulation
}
```

And:

```
@Subscribe
public void onEventMainThread(MyEvent event) {
    // some UI manipulation
}
```

Throws `CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` because the thread is the same as the posting thread (background thread in my tests).

Since version 3.0, the `@Subscribe` annotation is required so I don't understand in which case I should use the methods other than `onEvent`. Were they kept to facilitate upgrade from EventBus 2 to 3?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found the answer, as opposed to EventBus 2, the method name is not important since on EventBus 3 annotations are used in favor of Reflection, so the following will work:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void someMethodName(MyEvent event) {
    // some UI manipulation
}
```

I'm keeping this question here to spare the time for someone who might have the same question.

Comment: Yes. The have completely moved to annotations and the method name doesn't matter anymore. Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 6):

`@Subscribe` is the annotation that registers the method with the *EventBus*, in the past this was done with reflection, that's why you had to name the methods in a particular way (`onEvent`, `onEventMainThread` etc). This had two drawbacks:

1. Reflection is quite slow in Java, and
2. The naming convention is not immediately intuitive to new users.

Both drawbacks have been eliminated with the update, so now you can name your methods whatever you like and indicate in which thread you would like the event to run inside the annotations parameters.